# How can I debug `craft\web\User::_validateUserAgentAndIp()` warnings

Tags: craft3, session, logs, debugging

On a production site, we're seeing a ton of the following warning in our `web.log` files for (seemingly) every request, creating a ton of noise in the logs and making it hard to spot "real" issues:

```
<DATE> [-][-][-][warning][craft\web\User::_validateUserAgentAndIp] Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session.
```

[Under the hood](https://github.com/craftcms/cms/blob/004ab9ede036aa22bddd3f2b472c16e11bd8d55d/src/web/User.php#L536-L550) `craft\web\User::_validateUserAgentAndIp()` does the following

```
private function _validateUserAgentAndIp(): bool
{
    if (!Craft::$app->getConfig()->getGeneral()->requireUserAgentAndIpForSession) {
        return true;
    }
    $request = Craft::$app->getRequest();
    if ($request->getUserAgent() === null || $request->getUserIP() === null) {
        Craft::warning('Request didn’t meet the user agent and IP requirement for maintaining a user session.', __METHOD__);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

As far as I can see, (for front end templates at least) `craft.app.request.userAgent` and `craft.app.request.userIP` are correctly populated with the UA and IP respectively, so I'm not sure why/how Craft is throwing this warning.

We don't see the same issue in dev / staging environments, so I know this is likely to be a configuration issue, but I'm asking this question to try and understand what's going on so I have some idea of what to look for.

Question:

- What should I look for / how can I debug what's causing this issue?

*(Note: I know I could turn `requireUserAgentAndIpForSession` off in `config/general.php`, but I don't really want to do that from a security POV)*

Notes:

- This is on a site running Craft 3.3.13 (latest at time of writing)
- It's in a load-balanced environment
- We're using nginx as our webserver

Answer (score 1):

Most likely since it's a production site, it's from bots/scripts hitting the site's login page probing for vulnerabilities.

I'd suggest changing the [cpTrigger](https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/config/config-settings.html#cptrigger) config setting and see if the occurrences go down.

Comment: Thanks Brad, but I'm not sure that's the case in this instance: for one thing we're already using a custom cpTrigger, plus the (very large) request volume and the timing / pattern of requests is such that it seems to match that of "real" traffic to the front end of the site. Is there a way to see what path is being hit when the warning is triggered? I can't see anything in the dump of `$_SERVER` in the log output

Comment: Hrm... devMode would log a bunch more info to help you track it down, but you probably don't want to enable that on production.  You could do a quick module/plugin that had a custom log target (could still be file based) where you log whatever information you want regardless of devMode.

Comment: That's a good idea - thanks Brad, I'll give it a go and update here with an answer when I figure it out

Comment: Tom - has there been an update on this on your end?  I've been seeing similar issues on a production site to this and am also trying to find a good starting point for trying to troubleshoot.

Comment: @gjhead not yet - it's still in my backlog, just not at the top. My plan is to use a custom module to log out to a custom file some of the stuff we'd otherwise get from having `devMode` on, and use that to inspect exactly what Craft / PHP is seeing in the request.

Comment: I've noticed this too recently on a couple of C3 sites.